# Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined Value

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, push

This is my following code:

```
private convertFormat(src: Array<any>): void {
for (let i of src) {
  this.selectedMonths.push({
    id: i,
    itemName: i
  })
};

this.selectedMonths = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.selectedMonths));
console.log(this.selectedMonths);
}
```

However the "`.push()`" for when I try to push into the already declared Array<{}>, it gives me this error.

> Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
>   ; Zone:  ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: Cannot read
>   property 'push' of undefined

Comment: `selectedMonths : any[] = []` at the component class or `ngOnInit` `this.selectedMonths = [];`

Comment: I cant see your whole code but can you try this: private convertFormat =
 (src: Array<any>): void => {...} Maybe its a problem with 'this' not being your class's instance

Comment: @Z.Bagley I mentioned in my question that I have declared it as "Array<{}>"

Comment: @DrNio thanks! It worked! I declared it as 'selectedMonth: Array<{}>' but I should have made it this ' selectedMonth: Array<{}> = []'

Comment: Or you can declare it like `selectedMonths = new Array<{}>()`.

Comment: yup, cause if you don't it gets `undefined` value as every class member (type is not important for that error)

Comment: yes, that is correct @ConnorsFan - i prefer array literal though

Comment: @ezzzCash i added the snippet as an answer - i guess that is more visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`selectedMonths : any[] = []` at the component class or ngOnInit `this.selectedMonths = [];`